# how do I start creating a web service?webix+js+revel

Tags: javascript, web-services, webix, revel

everybody. I am a novice developer and would like to ask for advice.At the moment, I am doing an internship at the company and I need to create an assessment Manager project.Technologies that I should use: webix+js+revel (golang).First, I need to write the front, and make a "stub" - an emulation of the backend.Please tell me where to start, maybe some tutorials or examples that I can watch.

Comment: in principle, I wrote models that interact with an array of objects, (that is, all the standard methods, get,get All, create, etc.) But how to link this to the template is not very clear

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is very broad question. SO should be used for specific questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask